# PreparedStatement not returning ordered ResultSet

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

I am having some problems and I'm sure it's something stupid.

So I have a query like

```
SELECT name, id, xyz FROM table ORDER BY ?
```

then later down the road setting the ? doing a

```
ps.setString(1, "xyz");
```

I am outputting the query and the value of xyz in the console. When I loop through the ResultSet returned from the PreparedStatement the values are not in the correct order. They are in the returned order as if I had left the ORDER BY clause off. When I copy/paste the query and the value into TOAD it runs and comes back correctly.

Any ideas to why the ResultSet is not coming back in the correct order?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The database will see the query as

```
SELECT name, id, xyz FROM table ORDER BY 'xyz'
```

That is to say, order by a constant expression (the string 'xyz' in this case). Any order will satisfy that.

Comment: jeebus, you think I would have thought of that. But that cleared it up. Thanks!

Comment: You can only specify constants in prepared statements.

Answer (score 5):

? is for parameters, you can't use it to insert column names. The generated statements will look something like

```
SELECT name, id, xyz FROM table ORDER BY 'xyz'
```

so that your entries are sorted by the string 'xyz', not by the content of column xyz.

Comment: It's so obvious now that I see it, but I spent many hours trying to find why my results weren't sorted. This sums it up nicely.

Answer (score 3):

Why not run:

```
ps.setInteger(1, 3);
```

Regards.

EDIT: AFAIK Oracle 10g supports it.

Answer (score 1):

PreparedStatement placeholders are not intend for tablenames nor columnnames. They are only intented for actual column values.

You can however use `String#format()` for this, that's also the way I often do. For example:

```
private static final String SQL_SELECT_ORDER = "SELECT name, id, xyz FROM table ORDER BY %s";

...

public List<Data> list(boolean ascending) {
    String order = ascending ? "ASC" : "DESC";
    String sql = String.format(SQL_SELECT_ORDER, order);
    ...
```

Another example:

```
private static final String SQL_SELECT_IN = "SELECT name, id, xyz FROM table WHERE id IN (%s)";

...

public List<Data> list(Set<Long> ids) {
    String placeHolders = generatePlaceHolders(ids.size()); // Should return "?,?,?..."
    String sql = String.format(SQL_SELECT_IN, placeHolders);
    ...
    DAOUtil.setValues(preparedStatement, ids.toArray());
    ...
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `"SELECT name, id, xyz FROM table ORDER BY %s %s"` and then `String.format(SQL_SELECT_ORDER, orderby, order);`

Answer (score 0):

The database will see the query like this

```
SELECT name, id, xyz FROM table ORDER BY 'xyz'
```

I think you should add more variable like order_field and order_direction

I assume you have a method like below and I give you an example to solve it

```
pulbic List<Object> getAllTableWithOrder(String order_field, String order_direction) {
    String sql = "select * from table order by ? ?";
    //add connection here

    PreparedStatement ps = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    ps.setString(1,order_field);
    ps.setString(2,order_direction);

    logger.info(String.valueOf(ps)); //returns something like: com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4PreparedStatement@a0ff86: select * from table order by 'id' 'desc'

    String sqlb = String.valueOf(ps);
    String sqlc = sqlb.replace("'"+order_field+"'", order_field);
    String sqld = sqlc.replace("'"+order_direction+"'", order_direction);

    String[] normQuery = sqld.split(":");

    ResultSet result = conn.createStatement().executeQuery(normQuery[1]);

    while(result.next()) { 
        //iteration
    }

}
```